# Is it possible to automate sending messages through Instagram DMs?

Tags: javascript, instagram

I'm attempting to automate my reach outs to friends through Instagram DMs but am stuck on the part where I have to search for the recipient.

Currently, after the 'New Message' button is clicked, I get a popup where I have to enter the recipient's name. When I use the following:

```
document.getElementsByName("queryBox")[0].value = 'someNameHere'
```

I can see the value display in the search field after I run the above, but it does not trigger a list of recipients that I can select. Should I be using another method of typing in the search box?